# Regular expression to parse a commented configuration file

Tags: python, regex, parsing

Edit: I'm really just curious as to how I can get this regex to work. Please don't tell me there are easier ways to do it. That's obvious! :P

I'm writing a regular expression (using Python) to parse lines in a configuration file. Lines could look like this:

```
someoption1 = some value # some comment
# this line is only a comment
someoption2 = some value with an escaped \# hash
someoption3 = some value with a \# hash # some comment
```

The idea is that anything after a hash symbol is considered to be a comment, except if the hash is escaped with a slash.

I'm trying to use a regex to break each line into its individual pieces: leading whitespace, left side of the assignment, right side of the assignment, and comment. For the first line in the example, the breakdown would be:

- Whitespace: ""
- Assignment left: "someoption1 ="
- Assignment right: " some value "
- Comment "# some comment"

This is the regex I have so far:

```
^(\s)?(\S+\s?=)?(([^\#]*(\\\#)*)*)?(\#.*)?$
```

I'm terrible with regex, so feel free to tear it apart!

Using Python's `re.findAll()`, this is returning:

- 0th index: the whitespace, as it should be
- 1st index: the left side of the assignment
- 2nd index: The right side of the assignment, up to the first hash, whether escaped or not (which is incorrect)
- 5th index: The first hash, whether escaped or not, and anything after it (which is incorrect)

There's probably something fundamental about regular expressions that I'm missing. If somebody can solve this I'll be forever grateful...

Comment: Is this question specifically about regular expressions or about parsing configurations files with Python? If the latter, then why are you writing a configuration file parser? Python's standard ConfigParser module (http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) should do the trick!

Comment: Just asking specifically about that regex. I just want to know how to do it using a regex. I realize there are a million other ways to accomplish the same goal, including Python's built-in configparser module. Thanks though!

Comment: if you don't ab initio give evidence of not being clueless, answerers will assume worst case :-)

Comment: Can the escapes be escaped themselves? For example: `Foo \\# this is a comment`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your regular expression isn't matching as you want is because of the greedy matching behaviour of regular expressions: each part will match the longest substring such that the rest of the string can still be matched with the remainder of the regular expression

What this means in the case of one of your lines with an escaped # is:

- The `[^\#]*` (there's no need to escape # btw) will match everything before the first hash, *including the backslash before it*
- The `(\\\#)*` won't match anything, as the string at this point starts with a #
- The final `(\#.*)` will match the rest of the string

A simple example to emphasise this potentially unintuitive behaviour: in the regular expression `(a*)(ab)?(b*)`, the `(ab)?` will never match anything

I believe this regular expression (based on the original one) should work: `^\s*(\S+\s*=([^\\#]|\\#?)*)?(#.*)?$`

Comment: Oh, and hashes have to be escaped in regex's in Python. Now you know!

Comment: @apeace Really? The python documentation makes no mention of this, and I seem to be able to use unescaped #s without issue...

Comment: @apeace: `#` is a magic character in Python re syntax **only** in re.VERBOSE mode ... which you should be using unless your code is write-only

Comment: @john-machin: Yep--you're right about `#`. Totally misread the doc on that one.

Comment: @Dave: Your proposed regex: `^\s*(\S+\s*=([^\\#]|\\#?)*)?(#.*)?$` does not work. It fails to correctly identify a comment having two backslashes before the pound sign (i.e. `var=value \\# comment here`).

Comment: @ridgerunner The question says "anything after a hash symbol is considered to be a comment, except if the hash is escaped with a slash." It doesn't say anything about slashes escaping slashes, although I agree that's probably desirable behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I would use this regular expression in multiline mode:

```
^\s*([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*)\s*=\s*((?:[^\\#]|\\.)+)
```

This allows any character to be escaped (`\\.`). If you just want to allow the `#`, use `\\#` instead.

Comment: This is a correct solution which actually works. It is only missing an expression to match an optional comment after the value, and a `$` anchor at the end of string. Also, the `(?:[^\\#]|\\.)+` subexpression can be made *much* more efficient by applying Friedl's "*unrolling-the-loop*" technique like so: `[^#\\]*(?:\\.[^#\\]*)*`

Answer (score 2):

Of the 5 solutions presented thus far, only Gumbo's actually works. Here is my solution, which also works and is heavily commented:

```py
import re

def fn(line):
    match = re.search(
        r"""^          # Anchor to start of line
        (\s*)          # $1: Zero or more leading ws chars
        (?:            # Begin group for optional var=value.
          (\S+)        # $2: Variable name. One or more non-spaces.
          (\s*=\s*)    # $3: Assignment operator, optional ws
          (            # $4: Everything up to comment or EOL.
            [^#\\]*    # Unrolling the loop 1st normal*.
            (?:        # Begin (special normal*)* construct.
              \\.      # special is backslash-anything.
              [^#\\]*  # More normal*.
            )*         # End (special normal*)* construct.
          )            # End $4: Value.
        )?             # End group for optional var=value.
        ((?:\#.*)?)    # $5: Optional comment.
        $              # Anchor to end of line""", 
        line, re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)
    return match.groups()

print (fn(r" # just a comment"))
print (fn(r" option1 = value"))
print (fn(r" option2 = value # no escape == IS a comment"))
print (fn(r" option3 = value \# 1 escape == NOT a comment"))
print (fn(r" option4 = value \\# 2 escapes == IS a comment"))
print (fn(r" option5 = value \\\# 3 escapes == NOT a comment"))
print (fn(r" option6 = value \\\\# 4 escapes == IS a comment"))
```

The above script produces the following (correct) output: (tested with Python 3.0.1)

```
(' ', None, None, None, '# just a comment')
(' ', 'option1', ' = ', 'value', '')
(' ', 'option2', ' = ', 'value ', '# no escape == IS a comment')
(' ', 'option3', ' = ', 'value \\# 1 escape == NOT a comment', '')
(' ', 'option4', ' = ', 'value \\\\', '# 2 escapes == IS a comment')
(' ', 'option5', ' = ', 'value \\\\\\# 3 escapes == NOT a comment', '')
(' ', 'option6', ' = ', 'value \\\\\\\\', '# 4 escapes == IS a comment')
```

Note that this solution uses Jeffrey Friedl's "Unrolling the loop efficiency technique (which eliminates slow alternation). It also uses no lookaround at all and is very fast. [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124) is a *must read* for anyone claiming to "know" regular expressions. (And when I say "know", I mean in the Neo "*I know Kung-Fu!*" sense :)

Answer (score 1):

I've left a comment about the purpose of this question, but supposing this question is purely about regular expressions, I'll still give the answer a shot.

Assuming you're dealing with input one line at a time, I would go about this as a two-pass phase. This means you'll have 2 regular expressions.

1. Something along the lines of `(.*?(?<!\\))#(.*)`: split at first `#` not preceeded by `\` (see documentation on negative lookbehind);
2. Assignment statement expression parsing.

Comment: This seems to be what I was looking for. I'll go look up negative lookbehinds. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: This solution (using negative lookbehind) does not work. See my comment to John Machin's answer which suffers the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a regex for this at all, for the same reason I wouldn't try kill a fly with a thermo-nuclear warhead.

Assuming you're reading a line in at a time, just:

- if the first character is a `#`, set comment to the whole line and empty the line.
- otherwise, find the first occurrence of `#` not immediately after `\`, set the comment to that plus the rest of the line and set the line to everything before that.
- replace all occurrences of `\#` in the line with `#`.

That's it, you now have a proper line and a comment section. Use regexes to split up the new line section by all means.

For example:

```
import re

def fn(line):
    # Split line into non-comment and comment.

    comment = ""
    if line[0] == "#":
        comment = line
        line = ""
    else:
        idx = re.search (r"[^\\]#", line)
        if idx != None:
            comment = line[idx.start()+1:]
            line = line[:idx.start()+1]

    # Split non-comment into key and value.

    idx = re.search (r"=", line)
    if idx == None:
        key = line
        val = ""
    else:
        key = line[:idx.start()]
        val = line[idx.start()+1:]
    val = val.replace ("\\#", "#")

    return (key.strip(),val.strip(),comment.strip())

print fn(r"someoption1 = some value # some comment")
print fn(r"# this line is only a comment")
print fn(r"someoption2 = some value with an escaped \# hash")
print fn(r"someoption3 = some value with a \# hash # some comment")
```

produces:

```
('someoption1', 'some value', '# some comment')
('', '', '# this line is only a comment')
('someoption2', 'some value with an escaped # hash', '')
('someoption3', 'some value with a # hash', '# some comment')
```

---

If you *must* use a regex (against my advice), your specific problem lies here:

```
[^\#]
```

This (assuming you meant the properly escaped `r"[^\\#]"`) will attempt to match any character other than either `\` or `#`, not the sequence `\#` as you desire. You can use negative look-behinds to do it but I always say that, once a regular expression becomes unreadable to a moron in a hurry, it's better to revert to procedural code :-)

---

On reflection, a better way to do it is with a multi-level split (so the regex doesn't have to get too hideous by handling missing fields), as follows:

```
def fn(line):
    line = line.strip()                            # remove spaces
    first = re.split (r"\s*(?<!\\)#\s*", line, 1)  # get non-comment/comment
    if len(first) == 1: first.append ("")          # ensure we have a comment
    first[0] = first[0].replace("\\#","#")         # unescape non-comment

    second = re.split (r"\s*=\s*", first[0], 1)    # get key and value
    if len(second) == 1: second.append ("")        # ensure we have a value
    second.append (first[1])                       # create 3-tuple
    return second                                  # and return it
```

This uses the negative look-ahead to correctly match the comment separator then separates the non-comment bit into key and value. Spaces are handled correctly in this one as well, yielding:

```
['someoption1', 'some value', 'some comment']
['', '', 'this line is only a comment']
['someoption2', 'some value with an escaped # hash', '']
['someoption3', 'some value with a # hash', 'some comment']
```

Comment: Point taken. I realize it'd be pretty easy to write it another way :P I mostly just want to know why that regex doesn't work. That's why I asked the question!

Comment: This solution (using negative lookbehind) does not work. See my comment to John Machin's answer which suffers the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking it down into 2 steps:

1. Escape processing to recognise true comments (first # not preceded by \ (hint: "negative lookbehind")), remove true comments, then replace `r"\#"` by `"#"`
2. Process the comment-free remainder.

BIG HINT: use re.VERBOSE with comments

Comment: Negative lookbehind does NOT work in this case. There is no way to know how many backslashes precede the # and the meaning changes with the count. (e.g. `#` and `\\#` and `\\\\#` begin a comment whereas  `\#` and `\\\#` do not.) Gumbo's solution demonstrates the correct way to handle this. But I do agree 1000% about your "VERBOSE mode with comments" suggestion!